# How to display table from SQLite database in QTableView widget?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

I created a SQLite database called "test.db". It has only one table called "table1" which is not an empty table.
I tried to display "table1" in QTableView widget but the widget displayed nothing. 
The database was connected and Qt Createor didn't detect any error. I don't understand why QTableView displayed nothing at all.

My Code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlTableModel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  QSqlDatabase test = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
  test.setDatabaseName("test.db");

  if (test.open())
  {
    ui->DB_Status->setText("DB is connected.");
  }
  else
  {
    ui->DB_Status->setText("DB is not connected.");
  }

  QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(this,test);
  model->setTable("table1");
  model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
  model->select();
  model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Row1"));
  model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Row2"));

  ui->tableView->setModel(model);
  ui->tableView->show();
}
```

I can run the program but QTableView widget diaplay nothing. Where is the problem ?

Comment: You can see what returns the `QString selectStatement()` and use it manually (execute) and see results. The most probable case is that you're querying table (or database) that you think you have data in, but actually you don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
test.setDatabaseName("test.db"); // after this line open database connection.
test.open();
```

Comment: OP is already doing this, and is testing the result of the `open` call.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".